# md5 cant convert filename entities

Tags: php, md5

I have problem with to converting filename to md5.

I have filename:

> 20072437_60-0001#12-07-2013^11.41.23.jpg

But it doesnt  work if I have '#' and '^' in filename. 
How I can get it work without removing '#' nad '^'.

My code:

```
    if ($inline === true) {
        $thumbname = md5($file).'.jpg';
    } else {
        $thumbname = md5($file).'-big.jpg';
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why those characters were allowed in the first place.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: mention the error

Comment: you're trying to md5 the file with an extension and then adding the extension, while you should be md5'ing the thumbname. That's what I think is the issue here. So, am I right? Your question is unclear.

Comment: we also need to know what `$file` is and `$inline`. I have voted to close as being unclear. You've been given an answer below so you will have to ask them. I have moved on since there were no responses on your part, or you have left the question only to return at a future date.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly for me??

```
<?php
$inline = true;
$file = '20072437_60-0001#12-07-2013^11.41.23.jpg';

if ($inline === true) {
        $thumbname = md5($file).'.jpg';
    } else {
        $thumbname = md5($file).'-big.jpg';
    }

echo $thumbname;
```

Output:-

```
960f23e66bdfdff1d10a53f4957387f8.jpg
```

**Another way of doing this (Which I think you are looking for)**

Is by creating a function to get eveything before the last decimal place:-

```
function reverse_strrchr($haystack, $needle)
{
    $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
    if($pos === false) {
        return $haystack;
    }
    return substr($haystack, 0, $pos);
}
```

So the final result will look like:-

```
<?php

function reverse_strrchr($haystack, $needle)
{
    $pos = strrpos($haystack, $needle);
    if($pos === false) {
        return $haystack;
    }
    return substr($haystack, 0, $pos);
}

$inline = false;
$file = '20072437_60-0001#12-07-2013^11.41.23.jpg';

$newFile = reverse_strrchr( $file, '.' );

if ($inline === true) {
    $thumbname = md5($newFile).'.jpg';
} else {
    $thumbname = md5($newFile).'-big.jpg';
}

echo $thumbname;
?>
```

This will output if $inline = true:-

```
0f068b6cd39ea23fc73c5c51ea08da8f.jpg
```

If $inline = false:-

```
0f068b6cd39ea23fc73c5c51ea08da8f-big.jpg
```

You can see an example @ http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10b6a2148b44601c3aacdc009336b0cde7989109

Comment: I'm sure it works, but that is md5'ing the file "with" the extension then outputting the md5 with an additional extension and unsure if that's what they want here. Probably why their code is failing.

Comment: I think they need to make their question a little clearer then, the the code works as is.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree.